# MongoDB sorting based on highest value of two fields of same document

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, pymongo, nosql

I have a `collection` which has the following fields:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "latestActivity": "2015-12-23 12:30:00",
    "activity": {
        "activity1": "2015-12-23 12:25:00",
        "activity2": "2015-12-23 12:20:00",
        "activity3": "2015-12-23 12:30:00"
    }
}
{
    "_id": 2,
    "latestActivity": "2015-12-23 12:34:00",
    "activity": {
        "activity1": "2015-12-23 12:22:00",
        "activity2": "2015-12-23 12:27:00",
        "activity3": "2015-12-23 12:34:00"
    }
}
{
    "_id": 3,
    "latestActivity": "2015-12-23 12:45:00",
    "activity": {
        "activity1": "2015-12-23 12:45:00",
        "activity2": "2015-12-23 12:23:00",
        "activity3": "2015-12-23 12:26:00"
    }
}
```

The `latestActivity` contains the latest timestamp of the other three activities.

Now the problem I have ran into is that I need to first compare the second and third activity, get the latest among them and then sort the collection based on that.

So the sorted order will be: 1, 3, 2 because for 1: actvity 1, 3: activity 3, 2:activity 2

Is it possible to do this using some query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not touching the subject of performance the query you are looking for is something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([ {
    $project: {
      "latestActivity":1,
      "activity.count1": 1,
      "activity.activity1": 1,
      "activity.activity2": 1,
      "activity.activity3": 1,
      "activity.sort": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $gt: [
              "$activity.activity3",
              "$activity.activity2"
            ]
          },
          then: "$activity.activity3",
          else: "$activity.activity2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "activity.sort": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "latestActivity":1,
      "activity.activity1": 1,
      "activity.activity2": 1,
      "activity.activity3": 1
    }
  }
])
```

You create a temporary field for sorting in the first projection (`activity.sort`) by using the `$cond` expression to compare `activity2` and `activity3` and return the greater, then you create a new projection which omits the activity.sort field.